# Stackoverflow Chat Markdown does not work with returns

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, markdown-rendering

In the stackoverflow chat rooms, specifically the one Im using, and others I've seen this problem.

When you return text (Shift+Enter) to type more, and then you try using markdown in that returned line, nothing happens.

So Basically...

> First Line: **Bold Works here**
>
> Second Line: **Bold Doesnt Work Here**
>
> Third Line: *this goes for everything else in formatting, except links, which still work fine*

Its very simple to reproduce, try typing into the chat, then hitting Shift+Enter to return, and type a formatting object in there. It wont work:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Bit of a shame about your edit, this could've made a nice feature request to finally implement a feature you want... but instead you've turned it into a rant

Comment: @NickA It was fine before, but now that I know this has been an issue for literally 10 years, It makes me mad that we are relying on the community to notice, and the developers or staff havent done anything in that time to implement a fix

Comment: As far as I’m aware, it’s not that we haven’t fixed it, it’s that we feel it shouldn’t be fixed. As Adam says... it’s intentionally this way. I don’t know the full history or reasoning behind the decision but it’s was an actual choice not neglect.

Comment: @Catija I'm pretty sure performance is a key factor here. Multiline messages can have 30K of characters, putting them through the markdown parser, either client-side or on the server would bring servers and browsers to its knees, if enough of those huge messages are thrown at the infrastructure. We don't want to make Nick cry, right?

Comment: @rene Nick’s a great guy! I wouldn’t want to make him upset. That sounds like a likely explanation. Lots of people don’t realize that the length limit is relaxed on multi-line messages so that seems like a reasonable guess. It’s probably supported somewhat since it’ll make multi line code and quotes (pretty sure about quotes).

Comment: I wish I didn't share a name with Nick... it's mildly infuriating

Comment: I'm not sure it's a performance issue (at least not just that). Mark Gravell explains his view here https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1183. I agree with @TaylorS though. At least set the limit to 10 rows or so instead of just one row.

Comment: I think it's more related to chat being very, very, very low on the priority list than with server constraints, parsing markdown in the few multiline chat messages (that can be long) is likely nothing compared to parsing markdown in the many new posts on Stack Overflow

Comment: Sorry about the rant earlier guys, I have chronic back and knee pain due to bone and medical problems, so I get very mad and grouchy due to the pain.

Its calmed down now, I just wanted to tell you guys that. I dont want to seem like a jerk all the time. anyways, @Markus Yeah I didnt really think of that, sometimes I like to return 2 or 3 lines to fit a whole tutorial or conversation in, and having the formatting blocked is VERY annoying lol. Having a couple extra lines with formatting WOULD be nice